# Is it possible to combine Windows 8 (Metro) C++/DirectX game with (Metro) C#/XAML launcher?

Tags: c++, windows, xaml, directx, microsoft-metro

Is it possible to prepare Windows 8 C#/XAML Metro application that will be able to start my game written for Metro, but in C++/DirectX? I need to prepare kind of manager that will be able to launch several C++/DirectX games one after another.

Answer (score 0):

I think one application should not be able to just launch another one, but you could maybe register a custom file format handled by some other applications that you could then use to launch them using the Launcher.LaunchFileAsync() method - assuming they are all installed.

On the other hand if you have the code for all these games - you could use one of the [DirectX/XAML interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh825871.aspx) techniques to run the DirectX code.